# SQL - Counting number of instances of each result on another table

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a postgresql db and a straightforward query that pulls data from a few different tables to report on specific items and their sales.
I need to count the total number of orders for each item, and I've yet to find success in doing this.

The query pulls each specific item available for sale. I need to query the "order_item" table and count the number of entries or each individual item... which would be the specific count of each item's "kitchen_item_name" on the orders table.

```
select distinct
kitchen_item.id as "id",
kitchen_item.name as "Dish Name",
kitchen_item.price as "Price",
kitchen_item.created as "Created On",
account.firstname||',
'||account.lastname as "Seller Name",
account.email as "Seller Email",
account.phone as "Seller Phone", 
address.address as "Seller Address", 
address.zip as "Seller Zip", 
address.neighborhood as "Seller Neighborhood"
from kitchen_item
left join menu_item on (kitchen_item.id = menu_item.kitchen_item_id)
left join order_item on (menu_item.id = order_item.menu_item_id)
left join store on (kitchen_item.store_id = store.id)
left join account on (store.account_id = account.id)
left join store_address on (store.id = store_address.store_id)
left join address on (store_address.address_id = address.id)
```

This count needs to be the last column in the output, I had 2 thoughts- the first would be a subquery:

```
(select count distinct order_item.kitchen_item_name from order_item)
```

Adding this line right before the "from" line, doesn't work.

So I'm wondering if I need to create a temp table and insert the original query into it, then join the count? How is this generally done?

Comment: Always join on the key - `menu_item` is already there.

Comment: @clamp right, well I joined the order_item table on the menu_item key... I had the impression doing it that way would make it more difficult to count the number of orders on the order_item table and have it apply correctly for each row

Answer (score 0):

Hell, I think I've actually figured it out!

```
select distinct
kitchen_item.id as "id",
kitchen_item.name as "Dish Name",
kitchen_item.price as "Price",
kitchen_item.created as "Created On",
account.firstname||',
'||account.lastname as "Seller Name",
account.email as "Seller Email",
account.phone as "Seller Phone", 
address.address as "Seller Address", 
address.zip as "Seller Zip", 
address.neighborhood as "Seller Neighborhood",
(
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT menu_item_id)
    FROM order_item
    WHERE order_item.menu_item_id = menu_item.id
    AND order_item.kitchen_item_name = kitchen_item.name
) AS "Total Dish Sold"
from kitchen_item
left join menu_item on (kitchen_item.id = menu_item.kitchen_item_id)
left join order_item on (menu_item.id = order_item.menu_item_id)
left join store on (kitchen_item.store_id = store.id)
left join account on (store.account_id = account.id)
left join store_address on (store.id = store_address.store_id)
left join address on (store_address.address_id = address.id)
```

The important bit being-

```
(
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT menu_item_id)
    FROM order_item
    WHERE order_item.menu_item_id = menu_item.id
    AND order_item.kitchen_item_name = kitchen_item.name
) AS "Total Dish Sold"
```